# Ionic Change Platform Style for Single Component

Tags: ionic-framework

How would one change the styling of a single component? For example force md styling of searchbar on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `mode` attribute to force the Android style regardless of the platform it’s running on.

```
<ion-searchbar mode="md"></ion-searchbar>
```